# read_html not retrieving all data from simple html page, instead returning incomplete html?

Tags: r, rvest, xml2

`read_html()` usually returns all the page html for a given url.

But when I try on [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mjaniec2013/ExecutionTime/master/ExecutionTime.R) url, I can see that not all of the page is returned.

Why is this (and more importantly, how do I fix it)?

#### Reproducible example

```
page_html <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mjaniec2013/ExecutionTime/master/ExecutionTime.R" %>% 
  read_html

page_html %>% html_text %>% cat
# We can see not all the page html has been retrieved

# And just to be sure
page_html %>% as.character
```

#### Notes

- It looks like github is [okay with bots visiting](https://github.com/github/site-policy/issues/56), so I don't think it's an issue to do with github
- I tried the same scrape with ruby's `Nokogiri` library. It gives exactly the same result as `read_html`. So it looks like it's not something that's specific to R or `read_html()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it's treating the assignment operator in the page as an unclosed tag.

```
fakepage <- "<html>the text after <- will be lost</html>"

read_html(fakepage) %>%
  html_text()

[1] "the text after "
```

As the page you're after is a plain text file, you can use `readr::read_file()` in this instance.

```
readr::read_file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mjaniec2013/ExecutionTime/master/ExecutionTime.R")
```